# Can I stack Microphones on a Nexia mixer?

Tags: microphone, mixer

We have a small meeting room, and we just bought some new wired microphones to replace the wireless omni mics we had in there before. The sound is infinitely better, but we're realizing there were other benefits to having the wireless system.

We have a 10 channel [Nexia CS](https://www.biamp.com/products/nexia/nexia-fixed-audio-dsp) mixer, and the wireless reciever is a [Revo Labs HD](https://uc.yamaha.com/getmedia/1ed715b6-1c81-4be5-9c80-1b7108ec2d5f/MN-EXEC-WIRELESS-MIC-SYSTEM-20180504-EN.pdf).

We're using all 10 channels (8 for mics, and 2 for media), so I don't have any open channels, but I'm wondering if I can get away with *stacking* some. Both devices use the mini-phoenix connectors, so it would be easy to stick a couple wires into the same connector, I'm just wondering if I could get away with it for the amount of use it's going to get.

I'm not concerned about losing level controls, because the wireless receiver levels can be adjusted separate from the mixer, but I've only got two channels on the mixer I can work with, because the other 8 are using phantom power. The two media channels are only used during presentations, and will rarely be used to play audio the same time the mics are in use.

Can I stack a bunch of outputs into one or two inputs (accepting the resulting control limitations)? If so, can I shove as many wires into the connector as can fit or should I only put in as many as I need? This will only be a workaround until we can get another DSP.

Comment: This is a suck-it-and-see situation - you're unlikely to break anything, so try it and see if it works. I can't see any reason why this would be a really bad idea.

Comment: @Mark I gave it a try, and the audio came out sounding all muffled. My voice sounded as though I was using a synthesizer to produce a demon-batman voice.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't break anything doing this, and it will work, however you may find the levels will be lower than expected.

As Mark suggested, give it a try, and if the levels are fine then you are good, if not, best grab another mixer.